# Database Relation source depending on field

Tags: mysql, database, database-relations

I have a database of **projects** and their parent **companies** that manage them, each **project** and **company** has lists of **departaments** and **countries**.
However if project has field DEFAULT set to true, the list of **dep**/ **countries** should be loaded from its parent **company** instead.

My question is what would be the best method to design this ? Is it possible to do it "correctly" in MySQL or should i just manage it in application code (not too good).

Comment: Might the same country/department be simultaneously assigned to multiple projects?  What about to multiple companies?

Comment: a project belongs to ONE company, they both have one/many countries and departments (departments are NOT children of companies, they are more like categories internal to the system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression in your join criteria.  For example, using MySQL's [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
JOIN departments ON departments.departmentID = IF(projects.default,
    company_departments.departmentID,
   projects_departments.departmentID
)
```

Comment: wow i assumed (i assume too much) that you cant do conditional joins. How would I go about defining foreign keys in such setup?

Comment: @n00b: It isn't a conditional join... the `departments` table is *always* joined to your query, it's just that the join criteria that are used for pairing together records is contingent on the value in `projects.default`.  Both the department relationship tables (i.e. `company_departments` and `projects_departments` in my example) would contain an FK into the `departments` table.  The situation for countries would be similar.